# Brackets не хочет добавлять изменения на сайт

Tags: css

Через пару минут  работы в brackets изменения в css перестают отображаться в браузере. Они не исчезают, просто не меняются. Помогает перезаход в Brackets. Директория стоит вроде как правильно. В чем может быть проблема???[image: Снимок директории. Браузер тоже обновляю.]

Comment: Если вы говорите про Live Preview, то да, такое случается (тут Brackets не причём, виновато расширение), мне помогал перезапуск Brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема в Brackets - оно устарело**

Сам когда его использовал постоянно сталкивался с подобными проблемами.
Советую перейти на VsCode (Они похожи с Brackets, так что быстро привыкнешь)

Удачи ;3